# Kernel module getting loaded automatically

Tags: usb, kernel, usb-drive, dmesg

When i do  `rmmod usb_storage` and then `dmesg`
i can see the output saying usb_storage deregistered. But when i attach a flash drive and then  `dmesg` , it says

```
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[16565.129239] scsi41 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[16565.130134] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[16565.130172] USB Mass Storage support registered.
```

I dont understand how does it automatically get loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, the module loader is woken up when a new device is
detected. It's passed a "**modalias**" string, which identifies the device and
looks something like this for USB devices:

```
usb:v058Fp6387d0103dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
```

You can find your device **modalias** using the following command:

```
udevadm info --export-db
```

This is the section related to my USB drive:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
E: DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Flash Drive
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Alcor Micro Corp.
E: INTERFACE=8/6/80
E: MODALIAS=usb:v058Fp6387d0103dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
E: PRODUCT=58f/6387/103
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=530904794
```

This string contains the device class (usb) and class-specific information
(vendor/product/serial number, device class, etc). Each kernel driver
contains a line such as:

```
MODULE_ALIAS("usb:...")
```

Which must match the usbalias (wildcards are used to match multiple
devices). If the modalias matches one that the driver supports, this driver
is loaded (or notified of the new device, if it's there already).

You can see the supported devices (by modalias) and their associated modules with

```
more /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias
```

If you grep for the usb-storage device driver, you'll see it has some
specific devices it supports by vendor and device ID, and will also attempt
to support any device with the right (storage) class, no matter the
vendor/device.

<sub>[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device)</sub>

Comment: so what if i want to disable the module? and enable it manually whenever i want to? How should i do that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Create a new question to cover that topic please. As I answered your initial request please vote and accept my answer (See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks

Comment: i have edited the que. Please can you help me here?

Comment: Sorry but you should not extend the scope of your original question. Please open a second one (with eventually a link to this one). You'll always find people willing to answer on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: With your reputation level, you can also vote on my answer, just click on the (^) mark above the 0 please

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/442682/control-loading-of-kernel-module-automatically
Can you see this?

Comment: Thanks for creating a new question, we'll do our best to find the appropriate answer.