# Control loading of kernel module automatically

Tags: kernel, usb-drive

When i do rmmod usb_storage and then dmesg i can see the output saying usb_storage deregistered. But when i attach a flash drive and then dmesg , it says

```
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[16565.129239] scsi41 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[16565.130134] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[16565.130172] USB Mass Storage support registered.
```

How do i manually insert/remove the module without it automatically getting loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just blacklist the kernel driver:

```
echo "blacklist usb-storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

After that, nobody can use a USB flash drive in your system.

You'll have to manually "`insmod`" your driver with `sudo` to use USB devices again or if you want to restore the initial behaviour remove the module from the blacklist file.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer @Syivain Pineau, whenever a module is `blacklist`ed , it can still be added and removed using `insmod` and `rmmod` respectively. But for insterting you need to be there in the source location for e.g. to insert usb-storage, after removing it, you should run `insmod usb-storage at`linux/driver/usb/storage` .