# Make USB Pendrive/storage device write protected

Tags: permissions, usb-drive

I would like to enable the write protection to all pendrives connceted to my ubuntu 18.04 laptop.I tired

1.https://askubuntu.com/questions/442682/control-loading-of-kernel-module-automatically

2.https://www.techbeginner.in/2020/01/how-to-disable-usb-storage-in-ubuntu.html

3. chmod 444 /media/

none of the above method works for me .

let me know the solution to make all pendrives connected to my system will be write protected .

With above commands it working for one time , if I remove and reconnect again then its not working . I need to give command again.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If you always use `mount` to mount USB and never a GUI explorer you can mount using :

```bsh
sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/xxx /media/xxx
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/830240/1133128)

Comment: I would like to make any pen drive connected to the system will become read-only by default . I mean it will be automounted.

Comment: Am able to make the USB pendrive read only with ro option but when I remove and reconnect again the USB its not in read only .